# Create BigInteger Array from int Array

Tags: java, arrays, int, biginteger

I have an int array with me. Is there a way to convert this int array directly to BigInteger Array without iterating through the elements?

Comment: Wait, do you mean convert it to an array of BigIntegers where each `int` is converted to 1 `BigInteger` ?

Comment: Are you just looking for a one-liner or do you feel that you have to save the cost for the iteration?

Comment: You will need iteration. No escape from that AFAIK

Comment: I would like to convert in such a way that each int value is converted to BigInteger value.And yes ,I'm trying to do this to save the cost for iteration.

Comment: The cost of the iteration will be incurred, no matter what. If not your code then some other (library) code  will have to iterate over the array of ints and create the BigInteger instances.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the job if you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

```
int[] ints = new int[]{1,2,3};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints)); // [1, 2, 3]

BigInteger[] bigs = Arrays.stream(ints)
                          .mapToObj(BigInteger::valueOf)
                          .toArray(BigInteger[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bigs)); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj the line `toArray(BigInteger[]::new)` that you had previously did work and was in my opinion cleaner. Still, it works, +1.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Yes, changing it :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish this without iteration under Java-8 <sub>(and why does that matter, does the performance hinder your runtime by so much? Is this the bottleneck of your application? You must know that the iteration "cost" will take its toll from your application no matter if you use it directly or not).</sub>

Anyway, for the sake of completeness and to make this answer more useful, this is how you might do that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++)
    bigIntegerArray[i] = BigInteger.valueOf(arr[i]);
```

And if you decide you want to convert your `int` array to a *single* `BigInteger`, there is the constructor [`public BigInteger(byte[] val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28byte%5B%5D%29) that:

> Translates a `byte` array containing the two's-complement binary representation of a `BigInteger` into a `BigInteger`. The input array is assumed to be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

(And as you probably know `int` can be represented as 4 `byte`s)